# jQuery/JavaScript form validation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am using this code for form validation,

```
$("#btnaddregistration").live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var errorCount = 0;
    $("#formaddregistration").find("input").each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            errorfield = $(this);
            errorCount++;
            $("#modaldialogtext").text("'" + $(this).parent().parent().find("label").text() + "' cannot be left blank.");
            $("#modal_confirmation").dialog("open");
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (errorCount > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        document.forms["formaddregistration"].submit();
    }
});​
```

But form is not submitting. I have used all possible submit methods but I failed. Any idea where I am getting wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `$("#formaddregistration").submit()` yet?  You have jQuery available after all.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console section

Comment: Ya man, i have tried $("#formaddregistration").submit(); . It showing that f[a] is not a function. For this code i am getting document.form.formaddregistration.submit is not a function. Even i have return true; But still is not working for me.

Comment: Have you used a debugger? If so, what did you find?

Comment: Please show your HTML.  Also a jsFiddle demo might help.

Comment: <form action="addvahiclereginfo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="forms" name="formaddregistration" id="formaddregistration"><ul>
       <li>
        <label  class="desc">
         Name
        </label>
        <div>
        <input type="text" tabindex="1" name="name" id="name" maxlength="255"  class="field text small" value=""/>
</div>
</li><li class="buttons">      <button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="btnaddregistration">Save</button>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: Please amend your answer with the "edit" link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fy9sz/1/  according to OP's javascript function and html provided in comments

Answer (score -1):

First, you can improve your code quite a lot, that will help you in troubleshooting.

If the form is not submitting, make sure that the selector is actually working, ie, try something like `$form.hide()` and see if it hides, to ensure that it's not PEBCAK

```
var $form = $("#formaddregistration");
$("#btnaddregistration").on("click", function(e) {
    var errorCount = 0;


    $form.find("input").each(function(i) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val().length < 1) {
            errorCount++;

            // this line also needs improving..
            $("#modaldialogtext").text("'" + $this.parent().parent().find("label").text() + "' cannot be left blank.");
            $("#modal_confirmation").dialog("open");
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (errorCount < 1) {
        $form.submit();
    }

    return false;
});​
```

Comment: See latest comment by OP.  If `$("#formaddregistration").submit();` is not working for him, neither will your solution.

Comment: No, but cleaning up his code should help him to debug more easily. As it is, he fetches the form dom element multiple times, which is a pretty big problem in and of itself

Comment: I agree, however, the answers section is just for answers... that's why you're the only one who's posted so far.  Otherwise, we'd have ten answers, each with a different suggestion, guess, or troubleshooting tip.

Comment: I just posted a troubleshooting suggestion. If he wants to post a jsfiddle I could take a look. As it is, if you think you can do better, then post an answer yourself, I don't need your pedantry.

Comment: I am not posting a wild guess as an answer.  As just explained, that's not what the answers section is for.